# Ansatz in Riccati differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Are there any tricks to find a good ansatz for a Riccati differential equation?
Or anything that helps seeing what the ansatz will be.

Comment: see here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riccati_equation  i hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

The Riccati differential equation is a non-linear first order ODE.

The trick is a convenient change of function so that the Riccati ODE be transformed to a linear second order ODE.

The advantage is that a linear second order ODE is often easier to solve than a non-linear first order ODE. The linearity is the key.

But, of course, this doesn't mean that the linear second order ODE obtained is always solvable in terms of standard functions.

To transform the Riccati ODE (where $u,v,w$ are known functions)
$$y'=u(x)\left(y(x)\right)^2+v(x)y(x)+w(x)$$
to the linear ODE, the change of function is :
$$y(x)=-\frac{F'(x)}{u(x)F(x)}$$
The linear ODE to be solved for $F$ is :
$$F''-\left(v+\frac{u'}{u}\right)F'+wuF=0$$